# Remove Underline Border Materialize Input Text

Tags: css, materialize

I try to make the border bottom of the text box (input text) disappear.

It's working with `border-bottom: none` but when I write something the border appear again. I want to make the green line disappear (the image show the page when I'm writing in the input).

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Try Adding: input:focus{border-bottom:0px;} and input:active{border-bottom:0px;}

Comment: I tried, It's still not working

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In materialize.css

```
textarea:focus {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #03a9f4;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #03a9f4;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #03a9f4;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #03a9f4;
}
```

You can replace the color code with whatever you want to change the underline.

```
textarea:focus {
  border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 orange;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 orange;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 orange;
}
```

or remove it :

```
textarea:focus {
  border-bottom: none!important;
  box-shadow: none!important;
}
```

This is code :

[image: Code]

This is Result :

[image: Result]

Comment: The `box-shadow` css really helped. I needed a customized border, so that is fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> what you see is outline no border.For Fix it use `outline: none;`

**For Example :**

```css
input[type="text"] {
  border-bottom: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="">
```

Comment: It's something in materializecss, code will not help